# Format Cells from 2 sheets, based on 4 column comparison

Tags: excel

I need to find changed values in dataSet.

So I have 2 sheets with, in general, same data.

I have two columns: **docID**(which is unique key) and **rev**(which is not unique).

I need to find(highlight/display only/...) those rows, where for same **docID** from first sheet **rev is different** in the second sheet.

**UPDATE 1**

Sheet 1:

```
docID    rev
1        5
2        6
3        1
```

Sheet 2:

```
docID    rev
1        6
2        6
3        1
```

Only the first row makes an interest to me, as others did not changed.

**UPDATE 2**

simple if statement which should give some understanding what I need. In general this is done on similar test data set, so cells are incorrect.

```
=IF(NOT(AND($B6=Sheet1!$B6;$C6=Sheet1!$C6));1;0)
```

So values are NOT equal.

Comment: so column 1 is exactly the same in both sheets? If so, you can simply use `B2<>Sheet2!B2` in the conditional formatting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a custom formula in Conditional Highlighting:

1. Select the top cell in the column docID column, then select the whole column (in the example, I assume that this is column A and you select A1 and the rev is in column B, same structure in both sheets. Adjust as to your needs)
2. Goto *home*->*Conditional Formatting*->*New rules*->*Use formula to determine which cells to format* and enter the following formula:

   ```
   =VLOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A:$B,2,0)<>B1
   ```
3. Click on format and select the format you need.

Done!

Comment: It seems that my explanation was not quite good. I think i'll provide structure example; but thanks for your solution I will test it right away.

Comment: Looking at your update, I think the answer will do what you need. Though you need to change A1 and B1 to A2 and B2 - and maybe not select the whole column but only the range that contains data.

Comment: Ok. I'll check it and will leave a feedback soon. Thank you.

Comment: I got following `=VLOOKUP(O8,Sheet1!$O:$T,8,0)<>T8` but it doesn't seems to work. O8 is the first docId value, T8 is the rev value for O8.

Comment: hm. nope %) It might be that I do something wrong. But well thanks for help. I will try to work with yours guidencies :)

Comment: check out the help for vlookup. the third parameter must be the number of the column from your range in the second argument. i.e. if you you want column T, it is 6 (not 4 as I wrote earlier). Also, be sure that cell O8 is active when you enter this formula!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25598/discussion-between-jevgeni-smirnov-and-peter-albert)